# Angular2 NgbModal cannot Type In Form Fields

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the `NgbModal` component from `ng-bootstrap` for Angular 2. I have a form on a component that I am displaying in the modal but for some reason I am unable to type in the input fields. I searched for others facing the same problem but couldn't seem to find anything also didn't find any relevant bugs on the module's github page either.

the modal used: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Modal is opened using the properties:

```
{
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: true,
    size: 'md'
}
```

form component looks like:

```
<form>
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new crop to your inventory</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="quantity" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Quantity</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="description" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Description</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need more context.

Comment: Have you checked if it's a CSS issue? may be some layer is covering the actual input element. this code seems normal.

Comment: set backdrop to true.

Comment: Okay I took the form off of the modal and I'm still seeing the same issue, so I can rule the modal out as the cause.

Comment: I traced the issue to an ng2-sidebar component that I was using. For some reason it was blocking all fields on the page. Thanks for the help anyways!